# Camel Enrich and AggregationStrategy

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm trying to use Camel's enrich EIP with Custom AggregationStrategy  i.e

```
from("direct:xyz")
   .setHeader("...","")
   .enrich("http://localhost:myservice", new AggregationStrategy() {

       public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
         .....
       }
});
```

Output from HTTP endpoint returns XML response. I would like that to be marshalled and set to the body of the `newExchange`.

Currently I'm doing this by injecting `JaxbDataFormat` to the `AggregationStrategy` and calling unmarshall method .. i.e

```
public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
     AnotherObj obj = dataFormat.unmarshall(newExchange,
          newExchange.getIn().getBody(InputStream.class));

     Parentobj test = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(ParentObj.class)

     test.setobj(obj)
     oldExchange.getIn().setBody(test);
     return oldExchange;
   }
```

Is there any better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Just use "direct:route" on the uri and do the stuff you need with the new exchange on that route (call service, set headers, unmarshall data), the resulting exchange will be received as the new exchange in the aggregation strategy.

Answer (score -2):

A better (more concise) way may be to simply call the unmarshal method in the route itself and pass in the data format:

Java DSL:

```
DataFormat jaxb = new JaxbDataFormat("com.acme.model");

from("activemq:My.Queue").
  unmarshal(jaxb).
  to("mqseries:Another.Queue");
```

Spring XML:

```
<camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
  <dataFormats>
    <jaxb id="myJaxb" prettyPrint="true" contextPath="org.apache.camel.example"/>
  </dataFormats>

  <route>
    <from uri="direct:marshalled"/>
    <unmarshal ref="myJaxb"/>
    <to uri="mock:result"/>
  </route>

</camelContext>
```

http://camel.apache.org/data-format.html

You would do this immediately after your enrich/aggregation

Comment: My requirement is to not lose what is there in the Exchange. 

i.e If `oldExchange` prior to calling enrich has Object "A" in Body, then after HTTP endpoint is called which returns an  OutputStream. 
Then the subsequent steps should have Object "C" (having Object "A" and Unmarshalled Object 'B" obtained from Outputstream). All this for now can be done only in the `AggregationStrategy`.

The API for enrich does not provide an option to specify `dataformat` for the  `newExchange`. If it did Object  "C" could be directly taken out from `newExchange`..

Comment: You should probably clarify that in your original post as the statement: "Output from HTTP endpoint returns XML response. I would like that to be marshalled and set to the body of the newExchange." leads one to believe otherwise.